# How to handle not well formed xml on OSB

Tags: osb

Hi I am using OSB 11g in my project.

I am receiving some data's that are not XML or there are not well formed.

When my proxy are set to "Messaging service" I am able to handle my receiving data's in JavaCallouts

But .. when I choose "Any XML service" before I handle the receiving data OSB tries to parse the data

and raises error : Failure while unmarshalling message: Failed to parse XML text.

I don't need to parse the data, I just want to check what data I received, guess who is sending

it and just print it into a file.

Is there any way to handle the receiving data when error as a string using "Any XML service" ?

Answer (score 3):

You can choose "messaging service" as service type and "Text" as request message type. 
This would prevent OSB from parsing data as XML.

you would be forced to parse the data as String but I see that is no issue for you.

Comment: Is it imposible with "Any XML service" ? I have to choose "Any XML service"

Comment: It is impossible to my knowledge. Why do you have to choose "any XML service"?

Comment: The entire project is based on any XML service and it works fine. It is to risky to change it.

Comment: If your data is not well-formed XML, you cannot use "Any XML". If it were a pass-through service, then OSB may skip parsing step, but since you're passing it down to Callout, the parsing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select "message type" as service type. In the proxy message flow use XQuery function "inlineXML()" to retrieve required information.Hope this helps.